# where in sql server query update number list one field to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, where-in

I am using SQL Server, and in the query below, I have a concern.  I am not sure if the field on the left will update with the field on the right (coming from the same table) when I do a where in list.

```
update loc 
set locShortName = locName 
where locid in (3,4,11,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,24,32,41,45,68,69,77,82,85)

update loc set locShortName = locName where locid = 3 (move to next record in the list)      
update loc set locShortName = locName where locid = 4 (move to next record in the list)
update loc set locShortName = locName where locid = 11(move to next record in the list)
```

and so on...

I would think it would take the fist number in the list and address the field value setting, then move to the next in the list.

Are my expectations correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update loc set locShortName = locName where locid in 
(3,4,11,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,24,32,41,45,68,69,77,82,85)
```

You can consider that it works like this:

Take a row.
If locid is in the list, will take the locName of that row and put it in locShortName.

Take another row.
If locid is in the list, will take the locName of that row and put it in locShortName.

take another row.
if locid isn't in the list, it won't do anything.

And so on

It do not process one each at time, but the concept result will be something like this

Answer (score 2):

That looks correct to me.  Whenever I write a one-off update query like this I always test it on a copy of the table(s) first.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are almost correct, it doe not process one record at a time, but processes the whole set of records. It would pull at the records where locid = ... and then update the locShortname field to the locname field in each record in one fell swoop.  You should never think of in terms of processing individual records when writing SQl code, only of processing sets of records.

Answer (score 0):

The previous two answers aren't incorrect, it will read and update all records within a single implicit transaction (begins and finishes with query).  The update portion of the query will map the 'locShortName' and 'locName' values from the same record.

I find the easiest way to know what will be updated is to write your update queries as follows.  After I am done I usually remove the side-effect syntax.

```
--update l
--set locShortName = locName 
select locShortName = locName
from loc as l
where locid in (3,4,11,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21,24,32,41,45,68,69,77,82,85);
```

As I said, when you're finished either remove the select line(s) and uncomment the update/set lines or remove the side-effecting syntax.  This format can be useful if you want to join to other tables as well.

Just make sure every time you change your select statement, you make a corrisponding change to your update statement (even though it is commented).

Another good practice when you are not sure of the outcome of queries is to begin a transaction so you can check its resulting changes and row counts.  Then you either can commit or rollback the transaction as desired.  I would just warn that it will hold a lock on either those rows or the table so don't linger too long in an active system.